# Unable to consume wcf service from wcftestclient

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to consume a WCF service by WCF test client. While it is working fine in same machine when my WCF service/host and client are in different machine it is giving error as

> "Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://10.15.4.116:8000/hello If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
>   For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>   URI: http://10.15.4.116:8000/hello
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://10.15.4.116:8000/hello'.
>   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://10.15.4.116:8000/hello. The client and
>   service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an
>   error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error    URI:
>   http://10.15.4.116:8000/hello    The document at the url
>   http://10.15.4.116:8000/hello was not recognized as a known document
>   type.The error message from each known type may help you fix the
>   problem:- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not
>   recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.- Report
>   from 'http://10.15.4.116:8000/hello' is 'The document format is not
>   recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.- Report
>   from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading
>   'http://localhost:8000/hello?disco'.'.  - Unable to connect to the
>   remote server  - No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000- Report from 'WSDL
>   Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type
>   is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'."

Configuration file part of my application is :-

```
  <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy12" />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete configuration to find out the cause of the error

Comment: Post the **complete config** inside `<system.serviceModel>` - this snippet here is not very useful. Most importantly: which **binding** are you using?? It seems like you might be using `webHttpBinding` (REST-style), but the WCF Test Client is for **SOAP** messages only...

Comment: Currently my config file contains only this part , please tell me which binding should I use for WCF Test client

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559056/content-type-application-soapxml-charset-utf-8-was-not-supported-by-service

Answer (score 0):

It is the end of your error message that says all about the error :

Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Comment: How to handle it as in configuration file I didn't mentioned  "application/soap+xml"

Comment: you seem to have made an attempt to access to your server in a web-like manner (http://localhost:8000/hello?disco) i obviously don't know all about WCF, but from what i know parameters are not sent this way...