# Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service

Tags: wcf

I am getting the error below while trying to add WCF service to WCFTestClient. I went through a number of solutions on the web but I couldn't get it to work.

Can someone help me with the issues?
I am also providing my config file for service:

> Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by
>   service The client and service bindings may be mismatched.    The
>   remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message
>   because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not
>   the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file 
  must be added to the host's app.config file. System.Configuration does not 
  support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
               maxArrayLength="200000000"
               maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
     <service name="WCFTradeLibrary.TradeService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
            contract="WCFTradeLibrary.ITradeService">          
         </endpoint>
     </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint 
          above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faul`enter code here`ts for 
          debugging purposes,  
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception info`enter code here`rmation -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087515/wcf-service-using-basichttpbinding-is-still-sending-content-type-text-xml?rq=1

Comment: This is an old question but it shows up as the first answer in Google. I just want to point out that the error message could be misleading. The underlying error could be totally unrelated....which is happened to me.

Comment: I got this error when I added a constructor to a class.

Comment: For me the issue was I needed to add a name to the service behavior and then assign that behavior to the service for SOAP to work, rest was working without it though. Meta data exchange is needed for soap in my case

Answer (score 17):

I run into naming problem. Service name has to be exactly name of your implementation. If mismatched, it uses by default `basicHttpBinding` resulting in `text/xml` content type.

Name of your class is on two places - SVC markup and CS file.

Check endpoint contract too - again exact name of your interface, nothing more. I've added assembly name which just can't be there.

```
<service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the case matters as well. "Namespace.Service" is different than "NAMEspace.Service".

Comment: This answer led me to my own issue. During refatoring, the namepsace of my service changed. Which, as noted above, caused the switch from wsHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding, and causes the error. Great job Jan.

Comment: @Jeff - 2 hours of my life gone. Your comment saved me. Both my service name AND the contract had been refactored prior to parking the project and it was broken.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the example of a web.config that solve the issue for me. Pay attention on the <***binding name="TransportSecurity" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8">***

Answer (score 6):

In my case one of the classes didn't have a default constructor - and class without default constructor can't be serialized.

Comment: I was very surprised to find this was exactly the problem I had. Thank you. I could have done with a better, more explanatory error message!

Comment: I need to get this tattooed on my arm as a Memento style reminder. I hit this issue way more often than I'd like to admit.

Comment: IN ADDITION: I also had a couple properties that were read-only (had a get, but no set). Even if it did make sense to keep them read-only with the new default ctor, serialization requires "setters" to function, so the read-only restriction has to go.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, got it working by "binding" de service with the service behaviour by doing this :

Gave a name to the behaviour

> ```
> <serviceBehaviors>
>         <behavior name="YourBehaviourNameHere">
> ```

And making a reference to your behaviour in your service

```
<services>
  <service name="WCFTradeLibrary.TradeService" behaviorConfiguration="YourBehaviourNameHere">
```

The whole thing would be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
               maxArrayLength="200000000"
               maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
     <service name="WCFTradeLibrary.TradeService" behaviourConfiguration="YourBehaviourNameHere">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="WCFTradeLibrary.ITradeService">          
         </endpoint>
     </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="YourBehaviourNameHere">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faul`enter code here`ts for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception info`enter code here`rmation -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Enabling includeExceptionDetailsInFaults really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by others this happens due to service client mismatch.

I ran into the same problem, when was debugging got to know that there is a mismatch in the binding. Instead of **WSHTTPBinding** I was referring to **BasicHttpBinding**. In my case I am referring both *BasicHttp* and *WsHttp*. I was dynamically assigning the binding based on the reference. So check your service constructor as shown below

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3f0E.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur when `WCF` client tries to send its message using `MTOM extension (MIME type application/soap+xml` is used to transfer `SOAP XML in MTOM`), but service is just able to understand normal SOAP messages (it doesn't contain MIME parts, only text/xml type in HTTP request).

Be sure you generated your client code against correct `WSDL`.

In order to use MTOM on server side, change your configuration file adding *messageEncoding* attribute:

```
<binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
             messageEncoding="Mtom" >
```

Answer (score 1):

My case had a different solution. 
The client was using **basichttpsbinding**[1] and the service was using wshttpbinding.

I resolved the problem by changing the server binding to basichttpsbinding.
Also, i had to set target framework to 4.5 by adding:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
```

[1] the comunication was over https.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was very difficult to identify the problem because of a large number of methods and class involved.

What I did is commented (removed) some methods from the WebService interface and try, and then comment another bunch of methods and try, I kept doing this until I found the method that cause the problem.

In my case, it was using a complex object which cannot be serialized.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand how this is a solution to this precise problem but a solution to all problems. Can you be more specific?

Comment: The point Rob is this problem is caused by many various reasons, I spend more than two hours trying to identify the reason without a luck, that's why I used this technique. What I realized is once you catch the method causing the problem, it will be very easy to identify the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my case same error was caused by missing

```
[DataContract]
...
[DataMember]
```

attributes in the returned data type.

Check for that and try addinging those and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error message. I managed to fix it:

In my case the error was that I missed the [datacontract] and [datamember] attributes in the parent class of my returned class. The error message was misleading.

```
[OperationContract]
List<MyClass> GetData();

[DataContract]
public class MyClass : MyParentClass
{       
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }      
}

// Missing DataContract
public class MyParentClass
{
    // Missing DataMember
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Is this another question, or are you suggesting that the author may be facing a similar problem?  If the latter, please edit your answer to make that clearer.  If you're posting a different question, post it as a separate question.

Comment: Noted thanks. I hope my edit makes it clearer. This could be the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error in trace logs. My newly created function in API was throwing the same error but to my surprise, the old functions were performing good. 
The issue was - My contract data members had few variables of type object. soap-xml was not able to handle it well, however, I can see that array of object types (object[]) were getting passed without any issues. Only a simple object type was not getting parsed by soap. This could be one more reason why the services throw the above error.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was our own collection class, which was flagged with [DataContract]. From my point of view, this was a clean approach and it worked fine with XmlSerializer but for the WCF endpoint it was breaking and we had to remove it. XmlSerializer still works without.

**Not working**

```
[DataContract]
public class AttributeCollection : List<KeyValuePairSerializable<string, string>>
```

**Working**

```
public class AttributeCollection : List<KeyValuePairSerializable<string, string>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error while using WebServiceTemplate spring ws
[err] org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. [415]
[err] at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:665). 
The WSDL which i was using has soap1.2 protocol and by default the protocol is soap1.1
.
When i changed the protocol using below code, it was working

```
 MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
     SaajSoapMessageFactory saajSoapMessageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(msgFactory);
     saajSoapMessageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_12);
     getWebServiceTemplate().setMessageFactory(saajSoapMessageFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by using **EnumMemberAttribute** for enum member's attribute. If you are using enum type as data contract and its members attributed with **DataMemberAttribute**, same error occurs. You must use **EnumMemberAttribute** for members of enum

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same problem. In my case, I was using transfermode = streaming with Mtom. As it turns out, I had named one of my variables (for a structure), "HEADER". This conflicted with the message element [http://tempuri.org/:HEADER] as part of the http service download. Clearly, one must avoid using "reserved" words as parameter name.

Answer (score -3):

I had to add the ?wsdl parameter to the end of the url.
For example: http://localhost:8745/YourServiceName/?wsdl

Answer (score -4):

check the client config file that identified to the web.config on the binding section