# Update Service Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

For a project for school I need to implement a WCF service in an existing project.
When I want to update the service references I got this message.

> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:510444/Service1.svc/$metadata'. The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:51044/Service1.svc'. Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:51044/Service1.svc. the client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf8'..

(see picture 1)

[image: error]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559056/content-type-application-soapxml-charset-utf-8-was-not-supported-by-service)

Comment: @StephenKennedy thanks will check this out! Didn't saw this topic before.

Comment: That's why including your error message as plain text is so useful :) I wouldn't have been able to find the possible duplicate without it. I hope that helps!

Comment: @StephenKennedy didn't work. Still have the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

The service needs to be running in order to update the reference. You can start it without debugging by setting that project as the startup project and then pressing CTRL + F5. Then you should be able to update the reference.