# error Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service - removed only with specific user

Tags: c#, wcf

we Client-Server that works with WCF.
for few days we are struggling with the error:
Content-Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service net.tcp:{{IP}}.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

now, the problem is that when we change the Log on the user that holds the WCF to specific user (only one user) everything works.
if put any other user or LocalMAchine it's not.

can someone please help us with this issue?

Comment: There is a problem similar to yours in this link, you can refer to it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559056/content-type-application-soapxml-charset-utf-8-was-not-supported-by-service/25302867

Comment: thank you very much, but it is not exactly the same. here I have a problem that only one user, a specific one, can run it successfully. even Administrator, fail to run and get the error above.

Comment: What binding are you using?Do you use WCF security?